# How would I convert a valid Javascript JSON into a dictionary in Swift 2?

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a dictionary from this [JSON](http://www.google.com/finance/data?cid=12607212&output=JSON) in an variable  of type `[String: AnyObject]`.

I am using Alamofire to make the request. However, the `responseJSON` response handler doesn't work since it is not a 'valid' JSON object in Swift. How can I go about tackling this?

Comment: This JSON is not valid. The keys have to be quoted.

Comment: Try to validate the json if you get proper response then try to implement it. Some times json data is not proper in format

Answer (score 2):

Your text is not valid JSON (you can check this [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)), as it's missing quotation marks around attribute strings. While it might be a JavaScript object, that's not synonymous with valid [JSON](http://www.json.org/). `NSJSONSerialization` (which is surely what's backing that function) will correctly reject the input.

You should fix your JSON - preferably at the source. You could do it by post-processing with string editing functions in Swift, but this is a bad idea.

Comment: I cannot fix the source JSON since its a Web API unfortunately. Is there a way to add quotations around keys?